# Replacing a substring in a text file

Tags: python, file, substring

Gotta write a function that receives a file path and a "new_song" string(aka def my_mp4_playlist(file_path, new_song). The function does 2 things: open the file and write the name of the new song in the **3rd line** of the file (in the correct position) and then prints out the new file content.

Starting file content:

```
Tudo Bom;Static and Ben El Tavori;5:13;
I Gotta Feeling;The Black Eyed Peas;4:05;
Instrumental;Unknown;4:15;
Paradise;Coldplay;4:23;
Where is the love?;The Black Eyed Peas;4:13;
```

Required print:

```
Tudo Bom;Static and Ben El Tavori;5:13;
I Gotta Feeling;The Black Eyed Peas;4:05;
**new_song**;Unknown;4:15;
Paradise;Coldplay;4:23;
Where is the love?;The Black Eyed Peas;4:13;
```

What I have so far:

```
def my_mp4_playlist(file_path, new_song):
with open(file_path, "r") as reading_file:
    data = reading_file.read()
    data = data.split("\n")
    individual = []
    for element in data:
        individual.append(element.split(";"))

    for song in individual:
        song.remove(song[3]) #this removes a space leftover as the last value in each list

    individual = individual[3][0].replace(individual[3][0], new_song)

    with open(file_path, "w") as writing_file:
        writing_file.write(individual)

    with open(file_path, "r") as complete_file:
        print(complete_file.read())
```

Unfortunately the replace() method overwrites the entire file content and only new_song appears there. How should I go about this?

Comment: What's the rule for the replacement? Surely it can't be *"the song on line 3"*, can it?

Comment: It is, the assignment specifically states to change the name of the song in the 3rd line in the file. Also, if the original file has less than 3 lines I'm supposed to add more manually lol

Comment: can i add that the 3rd line will not be indexed as `individual[3]` but rather `individual[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here is your issue:

```
individual = individual[3][0].replace(individual[3][0], new_song)
```

A simple assignment should do the trick:

```
individual[2][0] = new_song
```

Please note that I am using index 2 for the 3rd line.
Also, you cannot pass a list as parameter to `write()`, you can only pass a string.

You can use `join()` and list comprehension to build your string. Your code would then look like this:

```py
def my_mp4_playlist(file_path, new_song):
    with open(file_path, "r") as reading_file:
        data = reading_file.read()
        data = data.split("\n")
        individual = []
        for element in data:
            individual.append(element.split(";"))

        individual[2][0] = new_song

        data = "\n".join([";".join(el) for el in individual])
        with open(file_path, "w") as writing_file:
            writing_file.write(data)

        with open(file_path, "r") as complete_file:
            print(complete_file.read())
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, used a debugger to see all of the phases "in action" and understood everything, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I did not know if your replacement is always at the same place or has always the same name so I added another attribute where you have to put the name of the part which has to be replaced

```
path = "YOUR/PATH/FILE.txt"

old_song= "Instrumental"

new_song = "ABCDEFG"

def my_mp4_playlist(file_path, new_song, old_song):
    with open(file_path, "r+") as f:
        content = f.read().replace(old_song, new_song)
        f.truncate(0)
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.write(content)

my_mp4_playlist(path, new_song, old_song)
```

Answer (score 1):

I will just tell you the mistake in your code.

```py
individual = individual[3][0].replace(individual[3][0], new_song)
```

- You have mentioned it as 3rd element so `individual[3][0]` should be `individual[2][0]`
- This one replaces `individual` with new value of `individual[2][0]`.

  But you just need to update that line:

  ```py
  individual[2][0] = individual[2][0].replace(individual[2][0], new_song)
  ```

  which can be further simplified to:

  ```
  individual[2][0] = new_song
  ```

Comment: OP also said the 3rd line needs to be replaced but `individual[3][0]` is actually the 4th line

Comment: That's right haha
Changed it to [2]
But now I can't write the list to the file since it's a list and not a string

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as somebody said, you don't need to split the data, you can use `reading_file.readlines()`.

Secondly, you said you want to replace the third line, not the forth, but in your code you are doing
`individual = individual[3][0].replace(individual[3][0], new_song)`

Remember that lists starts with the index 0.

With that being said, here's what I think would work:

```
def my_mp4_playlist(file_path, new_song):
    with open(file_path, "r") as reading_file:
            data = reading_file.readlines()
            song_to_be_changed = data[2][:data[2].index(";")]

    with open(file_path, "w") as writing_file:
            writing_file.write("".join(data).replace(song_to_be_changed, new_song))
    with open(file_path, "r") as complete_file:
            print(complete_file.read())
```